# Could not read Sitecore configuration

Tags: iis, content-management-system, sitecore

I started working and installing Sitecore ......Created new Site ...Publish it on IIS ...and want to map it in Sitecore explorer 
on opening the Site in Sitecore Explorer .it gives following error

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
 System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Sitecore.Rocks.Server.Pipelines.WriteItemHeader.SerializationStatus' threw an exception. 
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Sitecore.Caching.Cache' threw an exception. ---> 
 System.InvalidOperationException: Could not read Sitecore configuration.
```

I have read similar post .

It was suggest to remove readonly permission from the site which is in IIS .
.I did that ...still same Problem

I checked the map path ..it is corrected as path in IIS
Please Suggest

Comment: Does the site work using the browser?

Comment: Does your IIS User have permissions over the webroot ?

Comment: Have you got any custom include files? If so, remove all of them. If that fixes it, add them back in one by one until it breaks to find the culprit

Comment: try to add permission read & write to this user IUSER,

Answer (score 4):

try to add permission read, execute and Modify to IUSR and IIS_IUSRS

Answer (score 1):

For all those still having above error:

Try selecting "good old web service" rather than "hard rock web service", if you are able to connect successfully, then the most obvious reason is incompatibility of Sitecore rocks with your visual studio.

[image]